# virtual printer for redirecting and pdf making

Tags: c#, printing, virtual-printer

I need help or advice how to solve my problem. I need to create a virtual printer (or something) that should do this two things:

1. It redirects incomming print job to the physical printer
2. It retrives printed document and converts it to the pdf/jpg/png or whatever format

Do I have to create especialy virtual printer? Do I need then create the printer driver? I have read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8916/Printing-Architecture) article about printing architecture in windows. Every printer has its own printer driver. This means that the spooler then modifies the print job based on driver. How can I than send this modified job to another pritner? Does exists also another approch except for virtual printer? Thanks for all advices.